# How to add size parametr to img?

Tags: php, wordpress, jpeg

How can i add size parameter to my wordpress image?

The code i use for thumbnail is:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail())
{
    the_post_thumbnail('full');
}
```

I simply want to change url of image from

```
<img src="website.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg">
```

to

```
<img src="website.com/wp-content/uploads/img.jpg?size=10">
```

Comment: You just want to have `?size=10` after URL generated by `the_post_thumbnail()`?

Comment: yes, that's all what want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) to get only URL of post picture and create an `<img />` tag with this URL.

```
if (has_post_thumbnail())
{
    echo '<img src="'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'full').'?size=10" alt="" />';
}
```